# Custom OAuth Authorization server for my web api

Tags: vb.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Trying to get my head around the custom OAuth2 authorization server that am planning to implement for my ASP.net webapi service using vb.net. I was successfully able to create this using c# and it works without any error, but when I convert the code to vb then everything starts falling apart.

when I run with my vb code then I get an NullReference exception.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.<InvokeTokenEndpointResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrantAsync>d__3f.MoveNext()
```

Below is my c# code for the custom implementation of OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider -

```
 public class CustomAuthorisationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{ 
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {

        string id, secret;
        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out id, out secret))
        {
            if (secret == "secret")
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }


    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        if (context.UserName != context.Password)
        {
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }

        // create identity
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        id.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        // create metadata to pass on to refresh token provider
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "as:client_id", context.ClientId }
            });

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(id, props);
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
```

Here is my Vb converted code -

```
Public Class CustomAuthorisationServerProvider
Inherits OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Public Overrides Async Function ValidateClientAuthentication(context As OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext) As Task

    Dim id As String, secret As String
    If context.TryGetBasicCredentials(id, secret) Then
        If secret = "secret" Then
            context.Validated(id)
        End If
    End If
End Function


Public Overrides Function GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context As OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext) As Task

    If context.UserName <> context.Password Then
        context.Rejected()
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' create identity
    Dim id = New ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType)
    id.AddClaim(New Claim("sub", context.UserName))
    id.AddClaim(New Claim("role", "user"))

    ' create metadata to pass on to refresh token provider
    Dim props = New AuthenticationProperties(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From { _
        {"as:client_id", context.ClientId} _
    })

    Dim ticket = New AuthenticationTicket(id, props)
    context.Validated(ticket)
End Function
```

Could someone please advise what am I going wrong?

Comment: which line causes the NRE?

Comment: When I debug, ValidateClientAuthentication method gets called and I do'nt get any error, it even executes context.Validate() line as well without any error but after that at the client side I get error. GrantResourceOwnerCredentials is not getting called called.

Comment: While debugging I also found that in the ValidateClientAuthentication method, the value of the context.Parameters is null as well. whereas in c# I get the grant_type, username and password. Not sure why the parameters are null in vb

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same situation and found the solution almost as I was reading your post.

All you have to do is to return Task.FromResult(0)

```
Return Task.FromResult(0)
```